# SQLAlchemy inserts failing - How can I find the data that is violating destination schema?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm using the pandas method `df.to_sql()` in conjunction with a sqlalchemy engine to insert dataframes to SQL Server tables.

Every now and then, the insert fails due to a record violating the destination schema. When this happens I see some variant of this message: `(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('String data, right truncation: length 36 buffer 32', 'HY000')`, followed by a massive SQL insert statement that is essentially unreadable (these are very wide tables). I've yet to figure out a way to quickly find the record that caused the error. Are there any SQLAlchemy methods or other techniques to at least show me the bad record in the error message, rather than the entire novel-long insert statement?

Comment: you can catch specific exception ([`DBAPIError`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError)) with try/except block and use it's attributes to display what you want (`DBAPIError` has `.statement` and `.params` attributes)